# how to possition a button "above" the carousel-control-next

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a carousel and I placed a button which supposed to stop the spinning
but the button doesn't get click instead the "carousel-control-next"  tag being clicked
how can I fix this?

** when I remove the "carousel-control-next" its works fine **

```js
    $("#carouselButton").click(function(){
        if($('#carouselButton').children('span').hasClass('fa fa-pause')){
            $("#mycarousel").carousel('pause');
            $("#carouselButton").children('span').removeClass('fa-pause');
            $("#carouselButton").children('span').addClass('fa-play');
        }
        else{
            $("#mycarousel").carousel('cycle');
            $("#carouselButton").children('span').removeClass('fa-play');
            $("#carouselButton").children('span').addClass('fa-pause');
        }

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-content">
        <div class="col">       
            <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                      <div class="carousel-item active" >
                              <p class="d-none d-sm-block">content1</p>
                     </div>

                      <div class="carousel-item">                                  
                              <p class="d-none d-sm-block">content2 </p>
                      </div>
                      
                      <div class="carousel-item">
                              <p class="d-none d-sm-block">content3 </p>
                      </div>
                </div>
                <!--create in the bottom indicators to show in which slide you are
                    the "slide to allow you to press them and move the the slide you want-->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <!-----THE BUTTON ------>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="carouselButton">
                    <span class="fa fa-pause"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give us the link of you jquery plugin plz ?

Answer (score 0):

It is almost 100% CSS issue, it could be easier to help if you provided codesandbox/codepen link. But you can try to apply z-index on the button if carousel controls overlap it somehow.